# Merging nested array using map in JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, logic

I am fetching a data from Laravel API this way

```
 $inventory = Gifts::with('allocation')->get();
 $response = [
   'data' => $inventory->toArray(),
 ]
```

The output for the above looks like the image below in the console

[image]

This is what is inside the 0: {…}

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bar 1",
    "allocation": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "location_id": "1",
            "qty": "2",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "location_id": "4",
            "qty": "32",
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "location_id": "7",
            "qty": "12",
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to get an output like this

```
{
    "isEditable": false,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bar 1",
    "location1": "2"
    "location4": "32"
    "location7": "12"
}
```

It's an array that consists of 100+ entries like this and the allocation can be more or less or maybe empty as well

What I have done so far

```
 const array = result.data(gift => ({ isEditable: false, ...gift }));
```

This adds "isEditable" field to the array.

Comment: Can you clarify the following please! Are you talking about an array or an object? Second, what is the logic behind getting your output?

Comment: It's an array, I am getting the output from laravel API using eloquent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map the `result` array into a new one that only includes `id`, `name`, and the `locationNN` properties.

In the `Array.prototype.map()`'s callback:

1. Use the spread operator to separate the `allocation` property from the other properties of each array item (call it `otherProps` e.g.):
2. Spread the `otherProps` into a new object, inserting the `isEditable` property.
3. Map the `allocation` items into a key-value pair array, where the key is `location_id` appended to `"location"`; and the value is the `qty` property.
4. Use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) on the key-value pair array to create an object, and [spread that object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) into the outer object to be returned.

```js
const output = result.map(r => {
  const { allocation, ...otherProps } = r 1️⃣
  return {
    ...otherProps, 2️⃣
    isEditable: false,
    ...Object.fromEntries( 4️⃣
      allocation.map(a => [`location${a.location_id}`, a.qty]) 3️⃣
    )
  }
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-merge-nested-data?file=src/App.vue)

Comment: This is perfect

Comment: Sure, that also works :) If you don't need immutability, your way might be easier to grasp.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses reduce

```
const { allocation, ...rest } = gift
const processed = allocation.reduce((acc, loc, idx) => {
  acc[`location${loc.location_id}`] = loc.qty
  return acc
}, {})
const result = { ...rest, ...processed }

console.log(result)
```